# Any way to track a Bitcoin scammer?

Tags: fraud

I have been scammed by a Bitcoin scammer imposing by the name Andrew Hamish. I have reported every possible way but wanted to ask if anyone knows how we can track the IP address by their walled ID or other means. 
He is using this tel: +447441393273
and this walled ID: 3Ncudh6CejAT9C56oX2NkcbQ4uJxXuZtmf

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to BSE. Sorry to hear this happened. I know of no way to reliably get an IP address associated with a wallet. Your best bet is the phone number.

That's a UK phone number. I'm not aware of your laws and cannot suggest a course of action.

If you're in the US, then you could start with consulting a lawyer.

As a default response, inform the authorities or consult a lawyer before informing the authorities. If the amount is large enough and you're in the US, they might be willing/able to do something. The authorities won't step in to try and track this guy for 100 USD of BTC. 100 million USD and you may be able to find someone willing to take an interest.

If there is enough value there, outside of official channels, there are private investigation firms / lawyers who may be willing to work on contingency. The fact that you have a name and phone number is a good thing. Not sure if they're real or not.

My point is, from a technical perspective you've hit a dead end. That wallet has only transacted 1.8 BTC:

https://longhorn.bullpay.com/?gateway=2&data=3Ncudh6CejAT9C56oX2NkcbQ4uJxXuZtmf

If the name/number are real then it would be much easier tracking and taking legal action against the person.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately seems the scammer is using a Bitcoin mixer service (they all do), as you can see everytime he receives some BTC the amount is split and sent (most of the times in batch transactions) to multiple addresses (and that probably happens many times).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency_tumbler

As you can see here

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3Ncudh6CejAT9C56oX2NkcbQ4uJxXuZtmf
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/d9620ffb35827b9e7fab59efbd8edb89ba4bdab2917b915eb3a834093a911e1e

So, in resume, it should be very hard to track the coins and impossible to get the IP address.

I'm sorry.